Is there a method of proving if a surface is rigid or not?
I'm studying 2-D closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I'm trying to find a $C^2$ isometric immersion. I know this problem is still open, so I don't see myself having any luck, but is there a way of taking a metric or the coordinate's on a surface and proving it's rigid? I know by Nash all surfaces have $C^1$ isometric immersions via additive oscillatory corrections. A $C^1$ embedding can't have any curvature though, which is partially why I think this works for all surfaces.
I believe by Cohn-Vossen that any 2-d closed, convex surface in 3-d is infinitesimally rigid, but is there a way to prove global rigidity for a surface with locally concave patches? Certainly a sphere with a flat top can flex in the locally flat region (though the deformation going from convex to concave is discrete), but do we know if such surfaces are globally rigid?

See for instance my answer here.

@MoisheKohan Thanks! So, given that positive-curvature $C^2$ surfaces are all rigid, and negatively curved closed surfaces don't exist, which category would such a surface fall into? One could consider it to be two open surfaces stitched together, one part negatively curved, another positively curved. Which category would this fall into in your response? Is any closed 2d surface with sectional positive curvature always rigid? Take for example $r = 1 + b \cos (\theta)$ for $b \ \in \ (0,1)$ If this is the case, why is the flexibility of $C^2$ surfaces in $R^3$ still an open problem?

I would say that essentially nothing is known about the rigidity of a $C^2$ surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is not positively curved everywhere. Convexity is a very strong geometric assumption. Without it, nobody knows what to do next.
